# Derivation of approximation of Error function

Tags: special-functions, approximation, error-function

In [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm) there are some formulas for approximation of [Error funtion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). I am intrested in the formulas $7.1.25$ to $7.1.28$, here is one of them ($7.1.26$).

$$\operatorname{erf}(x)\approx 1 - e^{-x^2}\sum_{i=1}^5 a_i t^i +\epsilon(x),\quad 0\leq x<\infty,$$
where $t = 1/(1 + px)$. The coefficients $a_i$ and $p$ are some decimal numbers ($p = 0.3275911$, for example) and $|\epsilon(x)|\leq 1.5\cdot 10^{-7}$. The others are of similar form.

> 1. How are these formulas derived?
> 2. How to prove that the relative error $\epsilon(x)$ is really as small as they claim?
> 3. What are the exact values of coefficients?

In the bottom of the page with formulas it is said that Abramowitz and Stegun took these formulas from C. Hastings: *Approximations for digital computers*. Indeed, the formulas are present there (starting at page $167$), also, there are graphs of $\epsilon(x)$, but again, no derivation or exact values.

Thank you.

Comment: These are, if memory serves, Chebyshev fits of a transformed version of the error function. There are nicer and more analytically tractable approximations now; you might want to search for the work of Serge Winitzki on this.

Comment: I have seen Winitzki's work if you are referring to *Uniform Approximations for Transcendental Functions*, but I think that his $\epsilon$'s are bigger. Could you explain what is Chebyshev fit and what is a transformed version of the error function?

Comment: That was one of his papers; there was another one that specially dealt with $\mathrm{erf}$.

Comment: Let's call the polynomial in your expression $p(t)$; you can rearrange your formula to obtain $\exp(x^2)\mathrm{erfc}(x)\approx p(t)$. Replace the $x$ on the left with an expression in terms of $t$. That is the function which you will be approximating as a series in Chebyshev polynomials. You might want to look up the literature on this, including "economization" of series.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. So probably you are referring to *A handy approximation for the error function and its inverse*? If yes, it references the first paper where he tries to find a global (Pade) approximant of $f$, knowing what expansions at $x = 0$ and $x = \infty$ are. The first expansion is Taylor series for $\operatorname{erf}(x)$, while the second is obtained as $1$ minus asymptotic expansion for $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$. In the "erf-paper", he exploits this method. I understand that, but motivation, why should one use an ansatz of the form used in the "erf-paper", is unlear.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. And what you are saying in your last comment is that I should use polynomials $T_k(t) = \cos(k \arccos(t))$, $0\leq k\leq 5$ (since the degree of $p$ is $5$) to approximate function $F(t) = \exp (x(t)^2) \operatorname{erfc}(x(t))$ and get $F(t)\approx \sum_k \alpha_k T_k(t)$? How do I get the value of $p$?

Comment: Ah, that parameter I am not too sure of; Cecil Hastings was (in)famous for coming up with clever approximations that seemed to have just come from thin air.

Comment: With respect to Winitzki: the reasoning is that you want to build a rational function (or any approximant, really) whose qualitative behavior at $0$ and $\infty$ is similar to $\mathrm{erf}(x)$; polynomials certainly cannot do that, since they cannot exhibit asymptotes as in this case.

Comment: Well, have you tried expanding the transformed function as a Maclaurin series, and re-expressing the monomials in Chebyshev terms? (As I said earlier, look up Chebyshev economization.)

Comment: I didn't use Chebyshev terms. I used binomial series for $x^n = (pt/(1 - t))^n$ and I get quite simple series on LHS in terms of $t$. Why Chebyshev? This is only another base.

Comment: EDITED: @Guesswhoitis. I tried to let $p$ be $p$ and solve $\exp (x(t)^2) \operatorname{erfc}(x(t)) = \sum_{i= 1}^5\alpha_i t^i$ for other coefficients. For $i = 1$ and for $i = 2$, I get the equation $p/\sqrt{\pi} = \alpha_i$. If I plug $p = 0.3275911$ in this and divide this by $\sqrt{\pi}$, I don't get $\alpha_1 = 0.34802$, so the question remains completely open. About Winitzki: I am aware of that, but ansatz $\operatorname{erf}(x)\approx \left[\exp(P(x)/Q(x))\right]^{1/2}$ is still from thin air.

Comment: Well, binomial won't get you anywhere near Mr. Hastings. If you'd tried looking up the things I told you to look up, you'd have already read about the "equi-ripple" and "minimax" properties of a Chebyshev approximation…

Comment: To be precise, I get $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (2n - 1)!!p^{2n + 1}}{2^n}{2n +k\choose 2n}t^{2n + k + 1}\text{,}$$
where $(-1)!! = 1$.

Comment: I did google *chebyshev economization* and I read [this](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c5-11.pdf). But I couldn't  make any connection.

Comment: I'm now telling you to try the economization procedure. Again: Maclaurin, convert to Chebyshev, truncate, and go back to the monomials. You should then see something like what Mr. Hastings had, or better. Abramowitz and Stegun should have the table for converting monomials to Chebyshev.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it now, what are they trying to do whit economization (read [this](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/MCS471/Lec24/cheb1.html)). Will try.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I wrote a programm in Mathematica, which works for series of $\exp(x)$  and $\frac{1}{1 + x}$. (both cases are taken from the last link). Unfortunately, if I plug $\frac{pt}{1 -t} = x$ in the asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$, I am not able to obtain Maclaurin series without using binonial series, since $t$ is in numerator and denominator. Could you help me with that last step?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Please?

Comment: I might come back to it later. For now: why are you using the asymptotic series and not the Maclaurin series? That's not what I told you to do.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I am not sure why did I try with $\operatorname{erfc}$ first. I tried to do the economization with $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ too, but a similar problem occurs: $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n + 1)}x^{2n + 1} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n + 1)}(1/p)^{2n + 1} \left(1/t - 1\right)^{2n + 1}\text{.}$$ Using binomial theorem (instead of series), I get $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1}a_{n,k} t^{-k}$. Now, on LHS, there are negative power of $t$, whereas on RHS, there is a sum of polynomials $T_{j}(t)$.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Sorry to bother you but ... I tried everything, but I cannot find the solution, even without binomial series/theorem. Suppose $p = 1$. If I try to express $f(t) = \operatorname{erf}(x(t)) = \operatorname{erf}(1/t  -1)$ and compute $f'(t)$ and than $f$ in the form of series, it is of form $f(t) = \sum_{n< 0} a_n t^n$. How can I proceed?

Comment: Antoine, I will need to review this again, which will take some time. It has admittedly been a while since I've ever had to manipulate Chebyshev series for approximation purposes…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. No problem and thanks for help.